Obfuscating Vue 3 for Production
I am trying to find a way to obfuscate my code for production. After building (vue-cli-service build --mode production) and running it with serve -s dist/, I can still see that my code is readable.
For example: Some functions from my vuex mutations:
, De = {
            setUser: (e, t) => e.user = t,
            setUserRoles: (e, t) => e.user.roles = t,
            upsertGroup: (e, t) => {
                const n = t.id
                  , r = e.groups.findIndex((e => e.value === n))
                  , o = {
                    title: t.name,
                    value: t.id
                };
                -1 !== r ? e.groups[r] = o : e.groups.push(o)
            }
            ,
            upsertEmployee: (e, t) => {
                const n = t.id;
                if (t.roles.some((e => e === Pe.z7.customer)))
                    return void (e.employees = e.employees.filter((e => e.id !== n)));
                const r = e.employees.findIndex((e => e.id === n))
                  , o = {
                    ...t,
                    title: `${t.firstName} ${t.lastName}`,
                    value: t.id
                };
                -1 !== r ? e.employees[r] = o : e.employees.push(o)
            }
        }
          , je = {
            fetchEmployees: async ({state: e}) => {
                if (!e.employees.length)
                    try {
                        const t = await (0,
                        y.Oc)();
                        e.employees = t.map(( ({user: e}) => ({
                            ...e,
                            title: `${e.firstName} ${e.lastName}`,
                            value: e.id
                        })))
                    } catch {
                        (0,
                        b.oR)("Unable to fetch employees. Please try again by refreshing the page.", {
                            type: "error"
                        })
                    }
            }
            ,

Here is my vue.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  publicPath: "",
  productionSourceMap: false,

  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        implementation: require("sass"),
        additionalData: '@import "@/assets/scss/main.scss";',
      },
    },
  },

  configureWebpack: (config) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      config.optimization = {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
          new TerserPlugin({
            terserOptions: {
              format: {
                comments: false,
              },
              compress: {
                drop_console: true,
                drop_debugger: true,
              },
              mangle: {
                toplevel: true,
              },
            },
            extractComments: false,
          }),
        ],
      };
    }
  },
});

Am I missing any important configuration? What else needs to be done? How can I minify/uglify my code for production?

Minification != obfuscation. What you show is properly minified code, except that it contains whitespaces. A minifier isn't supposed to obfuscate it to avoid readable names like "upsertEmployee". And you'll have a very hard time to debug it and possible side effects that obfuscation can bring, because replacing names like "upsertEmployee" with random strings can have unexpected consequences

Thank you for the clarification. Is minifying enough for production? What else should I do to prepare the app for production?

That's what everyone does, so probably yes. You need to make sure that source maps exist or not depending on your expectations.  They allow to decompile your code at production but this commonly is not considered a big concern, not doing this would prevent you from effectively debug your app in prod. IIRC vue cli which you're using (the question doesn't explicitly say this) already has reasonable defaults so you may not need custom config for minification at all
